# Add a list in another list with different types

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, casting, arraylist

In my Java EE project, I have 2 `ArrayList` objects:

```
private ArrayList<Sales_personRef> sales_personsRef = new ArrayList<Sales_personRef>();

private ArrayList<Sales_person> sales_persons = new ArrayList<Sales_person>();
```

My question is : How can I add my first list(sales_personsRef) in the second list?
These lists have different types and I cannot cast it...

Comment: That really depends on what those two types are and how they relate to one another.

Comment: Don't use generics , let the List take Object.

Comment: you want to add arraylist or data attribute?

Comment: I want to add sales_personsRef data in sales_persons

Comment: Do the classes `Sales_personsRef` and `Sales_person` have a common parent class they are extending? If so you could just use an `ArrayList<SalesPersonParent>`. Thats why Suhanshu suggested `Object` for the ArrayList, because every class extends Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert each items of the first list in the items accepted by the second List

```
sales_persons.addAll(convertSalesPersons(sales_personsRef));
```

with:

```
private static Collection<? extends Sales_person> convertSalesPersons(ArrayList<Sales_personRef> sales_persons) {
    List<Sales_person> persons = new ArrayList<Sales_person>();
    for (Sales_personRef sales_personRef : sales_persons) {
        persons.add(converSalesPersonRefToSalesPerson(sales_personRef));
    }
    return persons;
}
private static Sales_person converSalesPersonRefToSalesPerson(Sales_personRef sales_personRef) {
    //implement the conversion here
    return new Sales_person();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If Sales_personRef and Sales_person both extend another class, let's say `Person`, then you could add both of those types to an `ArrayList<Person>`.

Keep in mind that if you do it this way, then what you get out of the list later will be of type `Person`. You will then have to cast it back to its original class.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring your second list as an `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use polymorphism  concept here . make a  parent class say person and then extend it   that would work